# Spring MVC HTTP Status 404 error on war deployment

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

**controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/","index"},method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showIndexPage(Model model)
{
    return "pages/index";
}
```

**View Resolver**

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver()
{
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver=new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
    return resolver;
}
```

The app is perfectly working when i run directly in eclipse. But when i deploy its war to tomcat. It is giving 404 error as shown in the below image. can someone please help me?

[image: 404 error]

[image: 404 error]

Comment: May i know the error found in your project under java Resources

Comment: it is because of "maven out of date". not responsible for my main problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the deployment location after starting tomcat?

$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/

The UI resources (Js/JSP/Css etc) should be in the root path

$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/yourwar/views
$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/yourwar/templates

and WEB-INF should contain the compiled classes and libraries.

This generally is a build problem. Check maven/gradle (whichever build too you are using) to see your war definition and the directory structure you are using.

Also you can manually copy the UI folders in this structure and restart your tomcat to test if it works and then work on modifying your build file

Answer (score 0):

link : [enter link description here](https://blog.frankel.ch/chaining-url-view-resolvers-in-spring-mvc/#gsc.tab=0)

If you don`t solve. you add your web.xml and config.xml